# Semantic UI, change class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, validation, semantic-ui

I have an input code as below:

```
<div class="ui form">
<div id="wlsdom" class="ui icon input">
<input type="text" id="wlsname" name="wlsname" placeholder="WLS domain...">
<i class="disk outline icon"></i>
</div>
</div>  

<button onclick="validation();" class="ui  green button"><i class="eye icon">
</i>Show URL</button>
```

Here when i click on "show URL" button, its calling function named 'validaion()'. So in my js file the function validation is as follows:

```
function validation()
{
if (document.getElementById('wlsname').value == '') 
{alert("Please enter domain name");
document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.remove('ui icon input');
document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.add('ui icon input error');
}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is form validation. I want to change the class of the input element from default to error state if the field is empty. But somehow the script is not working. Or am I using it in the wrong way. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should use `document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.toggle("error")` instead of
`document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.remove('ui icon input');
document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.add('ui icon input error');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classList.add()` function cannot include space in its argument. If you want to add multiple class at a time, separate them with the `,` symbol. In your case, just use:

```
document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.add('error');
```

and remove this line :

```
document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.remove('ui icon input');
```

See about classList.add() function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Thanks this helped me..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.classList += ' myClass'` to  add a class

```js
const wlsdom = document.getElementById('wlsdom');

function validation() {
  if (!wlsdom.value || wlsdom.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter domain name");
    wlsdom.classList += ' error';
  }else{
    wlsdom.classList -= ' error';
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui form">
  <div id="wlsdom" class="ui icon input">
    <input type="text" id="wlsname" name="wlsname" placeholder="WLS domain...">
    <i class="disk outline icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="validation();" class="ui  green button"><i class="eye icon">
</i>Show URL</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validation()
{
    if (document.getElementById('wlsname').value == '') {
        alert("Please enter domain name");
        document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.remove('ui icon input');
        document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.add('ui icon input error');
}
```

it seems u lost a '}'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `error` class only, not with all classes .And add else statement `if is not empty` to remove the error class.

```js
function validation() {
  if (document.getElementById('wlsname').value == '') {
    alert("Please enter domain name");
    document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.add('error');
  }
  else{
  document.getElementById('wlsdom').classList.remove('error');
  }
  }
```

```css
.error{
border:1px solid red;

}
```

```html
<div class="ui form">
  <div id="wlsdom" class="ui icon input">
    <input type="text" id="wlsname" name="wlsname" placeholder="WLS domain...">
    <i class="disk outline icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="validation();" class="ui  green button"><i class="eye icon">
</i>Show URL</button>
```